# Create path (spline) from GPS coords

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a continuous path based on input GPS coordinates in lat/long. Is there a python library that will do this? The final goal is to do optimization so I need the path to be continuously differentiable to determine gradient.

I've been using GDAL, but it doesn't seem to have all the functionality I need.

Answer (score 2):

This calls for the `scipy.interpolate` package. This page on [Interpolation in the SciPY Cookbook](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Interpolation#head-34818696f8d7066bb3188495567dd776a451cf11) shows how to use the functions `splprep` to determine spline knots and `splev` to plot the resulting curve on noisy data in the plane.

The cookbook example (slightly shortened):

```
from numpy import arange, cos, linspace, pi, sin, random
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev

# make ascending spiral in 3-space
t=linspace(0,1.75*2*pi,100)

x = sin(t)
y = cos(t)
z = t

# add noise
x+= random.normal(scale=0.1, size=x.shape)
y+= random.normal(scale=0.1, size=y.shape)
z+= random.normal(scale=0.1, size=z.shape)

# spline parameters
s=3.0 # smoothness parameter
k=2 # spline order
nest=-1 # estimate of number of knots needed (-1 = maximal)

# find the knot points
tckp,u = splprep([x,y,z],s=s,k=k,nest=-1)

# evaluate spline, including interpolated points
xnew,ynew,znew = splev(linspace(0,1,400),tckp)

import pylab
pylab.subplot(1,1,1)
data,=pylab.plot(x,y,'bo-',label='data')
fit,=pylab.plot(xnew,ynew,'r-',label='fit')
pylab.legend()
```